# TimeZone not detecting DST

Tags: java, android, timezone, dst

I've the emulator set to this timezone:
`org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo["CET",mRawOffset=3600000,mUseDst=true]`

This is Brussels time, where there is DST, so we are GMT+02:00 in summer and GMT+01:00 in winter.

However, programmatically there's no way to detect DST in July 1970, but it detects it for 2011. For instance:

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

    if(tz.inDaylightTime(new Date(15638400000))){ //This timestamp is 01/07/1970 00:00:00:00 GMT
         System.out.println("daylight time in July 1970"); //Not printed, despite being clearly in summer.
    }
    if(tz.inDaylightTime(new Date())){ // Now, 28/06/2011
         System.out.println("daylight time in June 2011"); //printed, thats OK
    }
```

What's wrong with this code? There was no DST in 1970? The same thing happens with the offset, which according to javadoc, includes DST:

```
    int off = tz.getOffset(15638400000); //This returns +01:00, wrong!!
    int off2 = tz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()); //returns +02:00, OK.
```

Some ideas about this behavior?
Thanks.

EDIT:
I've made some tests for this timezone, and the first summer with DST is detected in 1977. After all, there has to be a starting date from which this policy was implemented. However, 1977 seems to me a bit late (oil crisis were in 1970 and 1973). I haven't found any official document confirming this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Belgium, but in Sweden DST was introduced 1980, so it might be correct that there was no DST for Belgium in 1970. 
But if it is of big importance for your application to really know about DST in 1970 then you might need to dig into the source code of the `java.util.Date` class or compare with result of the `java.util.GregorianCalendar`.

Comment: It is not important, but in other platforms (e.g. Blackberry) I'm getting other behavior, and I was trying to realize why. Following your advice and my own curiosity, I dug into TimeZone source code. Found that the TZ info is in a record located in /system/usr/share/zoneinfo/zoneinfo.dat, which you can pull with adb. However, I don't know which format does it use, so it is pretty unreadable.

Comment: This might be interesting for me too, I have found some info on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database and also http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/util/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfoFile.java.java-doc.htm

Answer (score 0):

Tested on a real device (HTC Magic, OS 1.6), it detects DST for Brussels/CEST even in 1970. So this is another example of different behaviour between emulator and real devices.

I'm going to test it again on a more recent device, to see if it there are different TZ databases across OS versions.

UPDATE
Tested on Samsung Galaxy Tab (OS 2.2), same behaviour than HTC.